# ScrollView заезжает под AdView

Tags: android

На Activity находится `ScrollView`, а под ним `AdView`. Часть контента из `ScrollView` перекрывается баннером. Как это можно исправить? Пробовал привязывать низ `ScrollView` к верху `AdView` и наоборот верх `AdView` к низу `ScrollView`. Тогда скролл не заезжает под баннер, но баннер выезжает с экрана. Пробовал добавлять `paddingBottom` к `ScrollView`, но тогда на меньшем экране остается пустое место между скроллом и баннером. Кто знает как это можно решить? Вот код activity:
    `

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titleStopTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/stopTimeTitleText"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgViewStopTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewStopTimes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adViewStopTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="xxx">
             </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewStopTimes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adViewStopTime"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adViewStopTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ХХХ"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот так сделайте часть, там где ConstraintLayout.

И удалите в топике свою ключ. Вы его выложили в общий доступ, люди могут напакостить)

```
ads:adUnitId="ХХХ"
```

Comment: добавить рекламы в свое приложение с чужим ключом?))

Comment: нет, забанить аккаунт. Если начнешь его использовать не на релизной версии получишь 30-дневный бан

Comment: о таком извращении я даже не подумал)

Comment: но конечно Роман прав - ключи никогда выкладывать не нужно, на то они и ключи

Comment: А что сейчас мешает, увидев эти комментарии, открыть историю редактирований и взять оттуда ключ? 

Comment: Я сказал на будущее.

Comment: Да, уже не заезжает без отступов, еще потестирую на других устройствах и отпишу. Спасибо большое! P.S. Да, с ключом я что-то затупил(